# Search substring in binary file

Tags: string, replace, hex, binary-data

friends! Please, help me with my issue. I have an application which processes data and generates output files (different formats, but mostly images). In every generated file that application puts it's watermark - string, that looks like **"03-24-5532 [some cyrillic text]"**. 
And every time I use that application, I need to edit each file in photoshop to replace watermark string with required one and it takes a lot of time.

Is this possible to search that substring in application binary data files (using Hex Editor or something else) and replace? Which is the better way to solve this problem?

Comment: a real example would be nice and where it can differ

Comment: I'm looking for methods like an old gamer's application named 'ArtMoney' uses to change different integer values in running processes in RAM. But I need to replace string value instead of integer. Does somebody understand understand me or no?

Comment: How do you know that "[some cyrillic text]" ends if you look at it? does it have the brackets? Does it have a space after it?

Comment: Literally strings looks like **03-24-5532 ООО "Автодиагностика"**. But I don't think that it matters. I'm looking for method which allows to search and replace custom substring in binary file.

Comment: If you want someone to write you a regex pattern, the fact that there are quotes surrounding the text is good to know